# "No project ID could be determined from the Cloud SDK configuration" when running psqworker

Tags: google-app-engine-python, app-engine-flexible

When I was going through the Google Cloud tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/using-pub-sub#running_the_app_on_your_local_machine

I got the following error:

google.auth._default No project ID could be determined from the Cloud SDK configuration. Consider running `gcloud config set project` or setting the GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT environment variable

I did 'gcloud config set project [my project name]' with no success.

What's the problem?

Update: I've deployed app engines previously without any problem. The problem only happens when I run the psqworker for this Pub/Sub function. I know my project ID and used it before.

Answer (score 6):

The first thing I would try would be:

`gcloud info`

This will tell you the account and project that gcloud is currently set to.

You may also find the available projects for your account with the following gcloud command:

`gcloud projects list`

Answer (score 1):

**Locate the project ID and project number**

There are two ways to identify your project: the project number and project ID.

The **project number** is automatically assigned when you create a project.

The **project ID** is a unique identifier for a project. When you first create a project, you can accept the default generated project ID or create your own. A project ID cannot be changed after the project is created, so if you are creating a new project, be sure to choose an ID that you'll be comfortable using for the lifetime of the project.

> **Note:** You should be aware that some resource identifiers (such as project IDs) might be retained beyond the life of your project. For
>   this reason, avoid storing sensitive information in resource
>   identifiers.

To locate your project ID and project number:

1. Go to the [Cloud Platform Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/)
2. From the projects list, select the name of your project.
3. On the left, click **Dashboard**. The project name and ID are displayed in the Dashboard.

Answer (score -1):

TL;DR 
Use `virtualenv -p C:/Python27/python.exe name-of-env` instead of `virtualenv -p C:/Python36/python.exe name-of-env` in the tutorial

I ran into a similar issue.  Here are the steps I went through and why.  Hope it helps!

First I tried to specify the id with the command `gcloud config set project name-of-your-project`
This resulted in the error

```
ERROR: Python 3 and later is not compatible with by the Google Cloud SDK. Please use a Python 2.7.x version.

If you have a compatible Python interpreter installed, you can use it by setting
the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable to point to it.
```

I thought this error was weird because the tutorial tells you to use python3 but it doesn't work.  So I created a virtualenv with python2.7 like so

`virtualenv -p C:/Python27/python.exe name-of-env` (I have python 2 and 3 so its easier to specify the whole path to the .exe file)

Then follow the rest of the tutorial with

```
name-of-env\scripts\activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Don't know why you have to use python3 when it doesn't even work.